# Can't do typedef neither for CVOpenGLESTextureGetName nor for CVOpenGLTextureGetName

Tags: c++, ios, c-preprocessor, core-video

I have some cross-platform code in `.cpp` file which converts `CVPixelBuffer` to `CVOpenGLESTextureRef/CVOpenGLTextureRef`. To make `CoreVideo`-related functions cross-platform, I do the following in header file:

```
#ifdef IOS_SHARED_SUPPORT
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CVOpenGLESTexture.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CVOpenGLESTextureCache.h>
#endif // IOS_SHARED_SUPPORT

#ifdef MAC_SHARED_SUPPORT
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CVOpenGLTexture.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CVOpenGLTextureCache.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#endif // MAC_SHARED_SUPPORT

#ifdef IOS_SHARED_SUPPORT
typedef CVOpenGLESTextureRef CVOpenGLPlatformTexture;
typedef CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef CVOpenGLPlatformTextureCache;
typedef CVOpenGLESTextureGetName CVOpenGLPlatformTextureGetName; // error!!!
#endif
#ifdef MAC_SHARED_SUPPORT
typedef CVOpenGLTextureRef CVOpenGLPlatformTexture;
typedef CVOpenGLTextureCacheRef CVOpenGLPlatformTextureCache;
typedef CVOpenGLTextureGetName CVOpenGLPlatformTextureGetName; // error!!!
#endif
```

It says **"Unknown type name 'CVOpenGLESTextureGetName'; did you mean 'CVOpenGLESTextureRef'?"**, despite of the fact that `<CoreVideo/CVOpenGLESTexture.h>` is included, and `CVOpenGLESTextureRef` can be used in typedef.

Can't functions be typedef'ed? 
Can you suggest some experiments? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't functions be typedef'ed?

Functions? No. *Function **types*** however may be aliased. You can obtain the function type with the `decltype` operator:

```
typedef decltype(CVOpenGLESTextureGetName) CVOpenGLPlatformTextureGetName;
```

And `CVOpenGLPlatformTextureGetName` will become an alias for `GLuint(CVOpenGLESTexture)`, the function type of `CVOpenGLESTextureGetName`.

That above of course doesn't do what you want, since I suspect you just want to give another name to the function. You can do that with a `constexpr` pointer to it:

```
constexpr auto* CVOpenGLPlatformTextureGetName = &CVOpenGLESTextureGetName;
```

And that's it. `CVOpenGLPlatformTextureGetName` will be evaluated at compile time as "another name" for the function you initialize it with.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I tried to remove `constexpr`, it's not allowed. Is `constexpr` qualifier a preprocessor guaranty that I will not change the object code of real `CoreVideo` function?

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk - It's not a preprocessor qualifier. It's part of the type system. It essentially means that pointer is a compile time constant expression that always evaluates to the same address.